# multiplying logical implications

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

i'm trying to prove that ~p → (p → q) is a tautology without truth table.
So what I did is distribute the ~p → over the (p → q)
so what I did is ~p → p → ~p → q. But I found that by truth table it's not equivalent to ~p (p → q). 
So the question is:
what is → x →?
How can I prove ~p → (p → q) is a tautology without truth table?
Thanks

Comment: Using the [equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) : $p \to q$ and $\lnot p \lor q$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: But it is better to modify the title: there is no "multiplication" of logical connectives.

Comment: You don't want to use truth tables, but which proof methods _do_ you allow?

Comment: prove by mathematical reasoning

Comment: All you'll be able to do is manipulate the formula into other formulas with where you're going in the OP. But a tautology is a formula that's true under all possible valuations. You can't show this without appealing to a valuation function or truth table; changing its form won't bring this out.

Comment: @RyanA but my book asks me to show that it is a tautology without using truth tables..

Comment: What are you allowed to do?

Comment: @RyanA Anything in discrete math except truth tables

Comment: What proof system have you been taught?  "Anything in discrete math" is actually a rather broad topic.  But Mauro Allegranza's suggestion is likely a good start.  If you define $p\to q$ as $\neg p\vee q$, then: $p\to q$ is true if $p$ is false or $q$ is true.  Which means $\neg p$ implies $p\to q$, so...

Comment: The formula is equivalent (by [Material Implication rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference))) to $\lnot \lnot p \lor (\lnot p \lor q)$ which in turn is (by [Associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Propositional_logic)): $(\lnot \lnot p \lor \lnot p) \lor q$  that is (by [Negation laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence)) $\text T \lor q$ which in turn (by [Domination laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence)) is equiv to $\text T$.

Answer (score 2):

The $\rightarrow$ does not distribute over another $\rightarrow$

Anyway, instead of using a truth-table, you can do something like this:

We need to show that $\neg p \rightarrow (p \rightarrow q)$

So, let's do a conditional proof: let's assume $\neg p$ and let's try to show $p \rightarrow q$.  If we can show that, then we have shown that if $\neg p$, then $p \rightarrow q$, i.e. $\neg p \rightarrow (p \rightarrow q)$

OK, so we need to show another conditional: $p \rightarrow q$

So, let's do another conditional proof: assume $p$, and try to show $q$.

OK, so now we have two assumptions, $\neg p$ and $p$, and we're trying to show $q$. How can we do that? Well, there are several things we can do:

Proof by contradiction: assume $\neg q$, and show that that leads to a contyradiction. Well, we indeed have a contradiction: between $p$ and $\neg p$. So, $\neg q$ is not true, and hence (we're obviously doing classical logic here!) $q$ is true.

Another way of deriving $q$ from $p$ and $\neg p$:

Given that $p$ is true, the statement $p \lor q$ is also true.  But given $\neg p$, that means $q$ (this inference is called Disjunctive Syllogism)